# Why getPersonal() returns null in the below case?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have been working with InternetAddress in Java. I used a below code snippet.

```
InternetAddress internetAddress = new InternetAddress("king<***@***.com>");
System.out.println(internetAddress.getPersonal());
```

In this case it returns king as output.

```
InternetAddress internetAddress = new InternetAddress(",<***@***.com>");
System.out.println(internetAddress.getPersonal());
```

In this case, there is no exception but null is returned.

Here comma is not enclosed in double quotes, then how it is accepted and why it returns null instead of comma?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be interpreting that comma as a separated list of senders, there is code in the parse() function specifically to handle commas, but I didn't understand the entire function, check the source code here: https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.java#L1051

Comment: Commas are used for lists. See [rfc822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [`InternetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) parse function documentation saying that the addressList parameter is interpreted as a comma separated list of address strings, it's very likely that java is seeing this as two emails, one invalid (empty) address, and one with no personal address.

Your constructor call new InternetAddress("xyz") is then passed to parse directly, as you can see [here](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.java#L119)

There is special handling for commas where it tries to detect commas as a list of addresses, which you can see [here](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.java#L1051)

Relevant Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse

Comment: Yes, and an argument could be made that it should throw a parse exception in this case since it's expecting only one address and you've given it a list of two, one of which is empty.